# How to remove a single objects stored on Java FileOutputStream

Tags: java, java-io

I have used this code to store Object to a file:

```
try{  
      FileOutputStream saveFile=new FileOutputStream("SaveObj.sav");


      ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);

      save.writeObject(x);

      save.close();
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
      exc.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

How remove the single Object??
How clear the file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, emptying out a file is very easy -- just open it for writing, and close it again:

```
new FileOutputStream("SaveObj.sav").close();
```

That will empty it out. If you were trying to erase one object out of many, though, that's a lot more complicated. You'd either have to read in all the objects and write out only the ones you want to keep, or you'd have to keep an index of the file offsets at which each object starts (probably in a separate file.) At that point you'd want to consider using an object database instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ernest is right in that a removal of a particular object from the object-stream is slightly more complicated. He is also right that when you want to empty a file, you can simply open it for writing and close it. But if you want to remove it from the file-system, it is fine to do it using the `File` object (do not forget to handle the exceptions and return values correctly). The following example may not be perfect, but it should give you a hint on how to achieve your goals with pure Java. Hope this helps...

```
package test;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String filename = "object.serialized";
    {
      List objects = new ArrayList();
      objects.add("String1");
      objects.add("String2");
      objects.add("String3");
      writeObjectsToFile(filename, objects);
    }

    {
      List objects = readObjectsFromFile(filename);
      objects.remove(1);
      writeObjectsToFile(filename, objects);
    }

    {
      List objects = readObjectsFromFile(filename);
      for (Object object : objects) {
        System.out.println(object);
      }
    }

    emptyFile(filename);
    deleteFile(filename);
  }

  private static void emptyFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
      os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } finally {
      if (os != null) {
        os.close();
      }
    }
  }

  private static void deleteFile(String filename) {
    File f = new File(filename);
    if (f.delete()) {
      System.out.println(filename + " deleted sucessfully...");
    } else {
      System.out.println(filename + " deletion failed!");
    }
  }

  private static void writeObjectsToFile(String filename, List objects) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
      os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
      for (Object object : objects) {
        oos.writeObject(object);
      }
      oos.flush();
    } finally {
      if (os != null) {
        os.close();
      }
    }
  }

  private static List readObjectsFromFile(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List objects = new ArrayList();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = new FileInputStream(filename);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
      while (true) {
        try {
          Object object = ois.readObject();
          objects.add(object);
        } catch (EOFException ex) {
          break;
        }
      }
    } finally {
      if (is != null) {
        is.close();
      }
    }
    return objects;
  }

}
```

Outputs:

```
String1
String3
object.serialized deleted sucessfully...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there was a long time from this subject, but just to help future coming people, what works for me was to write the object again as a null value:

```
public static void writeIncidentsObjectsInCache(Object object) throws IOException {
    writeObject(INCIDENTS_CACHE, object); }

public static Object readIncidentsObjectFromCache() throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    return readObject(INCIDENTS_CACHE); }

public static void clearIncidents() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    writeIncidentsObjectsInCache(null); }

public static void writeObject(String key, Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = TheAAApp.getApp().openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object readObject(String key) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = TheAAApp.getApp().openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```